# Codeigniter and ezPDF adding images

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf-generation

I am currently following [this](http://codeigniter.com/news/codeigniter_community_voice_generating_pdf_files_using_codeigniter/) tutorial in Codeigniter and was wondering how I can add
an image to a pdf, the [manual](http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/readme.pdf) on ezpdf's page doesn't specifically state on what kind of path I need to input, I tried everything and the PDF just would not load or show an image.

For your reference I am using the code below to add an image.

```
$image = base_url()."system/application/images/logo.jpg";
$this->cezpdf->ezImage( $image );
```

Comment: Really no one? is the library that out of date?

Comment: I've used fpdf along with CodeIgniter and it was a great success. If you're willing to use another library, tell me so I can develop a more in-depth answer.

Comment: @Cronco - I just tried using it and formatting was a bit difficult for me, especially in making tables for CodeIgniter results. It's just frustrating that all I need is 1 image to add to the pdf and then I have to redo everything just because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) with codeigniter and here's how I added the image

```
function setReportGeneralPageHead($report_name, $print_date){
      $this->fpdf->Image(base_url().'system/application/images/somelogo.jpg',10,3,60,0,'');
      $this->fpdf->Image(base_url().'system/application/images/another-logo.png',225,10,60,0,'');


       $this->fpdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
       $this->fpdf->Cell(140,45,$report_name,'',0,'L');
       $this->fpdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
       $this->fpdf->Cell(135,45, "Generated on: ".$print_date,'',0,'R');
       //$this->fpdf->Line(20, 20, 190, 20);
       $this->fpdf->Ln(15);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `site_url()` and it works for me:

```
 $this->cezpdf->ezImage(site_url("image_path"));
```

cezpdf `fopen`s the url and caches it in its temp directory.