# Image not appearing using codeigniter and cezpdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, ezpdf

I built a PDF using Cezpdf and codeigniter in PHP.  I have been asked to change the image in the PDF.  I uploaded the new image, added it to my code, but nothing appears on the page.  I do not get any errors either.

Here is my code:

```
       $pdfobj->selectFont('./fonts/Helvetica.afm');
       $pdfobj->addPngFromFile(FCPATH . 'img/logo.png', 20, 770, 180, 60);
       $pdfobj->ezSetDy(8);
```

With the old image, my code was exactly the same but the logo.png was orig-logo.png.

I've checked the path of the file and the x and y coordinates and the sizing and don't get any error messages, just a PDF without an image.  Can anyone help?

Comment: *I used site_url() and it works for me:* https://stackoverflow.com/a/7279405/2275490

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image size is 37 KB, which (surprisingly) is too large for the ezPdf.  After resizing, everything works great.